# Check dependencies

Tags: xcode, dependencies, fmdb, cocoalumberjack

[image: Sample 1] and  [image: Sample 2]. I use three Frameworks namely, `FMDB`; `CocoaLumberjack`; `CDTDatastore`. I'm running into these errors:

Check dependencies

> Unable to run command **Ld CocoaLumberjack** - this target might
>   include its own product.
>
> Unable to run command **Touch CocoaLumberjack.framework** - this
>   target might include its own product.
>
> Unable to run command **CodeSign CocoaLumberjack.framework** - this
>   target might include its own product.

The error pattern is repeating in all the three framework